# JavaScript how to replace %20 to space

Tags: javascript, angularjs, urldecode

I am trying to retrieve values from the url and displaying it in my web page using angular JS. what i am doing is

1) saving the entire url to a variable and split it so that i can filter to the value i need.

2) However when there is a space it is shown as %20. i want this %20 to be displayed as space itself.

Example : john doe is shown as john%20doe

Controller

```
function InboxController($scope, $http, $cookieStore, $location) {
    $scope.single_mail = function()
      { 
        var url = $location.url();
        var split_url = url.split('=');
        var mess_id = split_url[1];
        var from =  split_url[2];
        var id_value = mess_id.split('&');
        var inbox_id = id_value[0];
        var from_value = from.split('&');
        $scope.inbox_from = from_value[0];
        $scope.single_message = [];
        $scope.single_message = [];
        var single_inbox_mail ="https://phoe.manage.com/app/inbox/message.html?contactid="+conId+"&token="+token+"&id="+inbox_id;
        $http.get(single_inbox_mail).success(function(response) {
        $scope.single_message = response[0];
       });
```

HTML view

```
<div class="page" data-ng-controller="InboxController">
  <div class="row" ng-init="single_mail()">
    <div class="mail-header row">
      <div class="col-md-8">
        <h3>{{single_message.subject}}</h3>
        <h4>From : <strong>{{inbox_from}}</strong></h4>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="mail-content">
      <p>{{single_message.body}}</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

this is encoded url part, you should use [`decodeURIComponent()`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_decodeuricomponent.asp) function and pass encoded string in first param, see sample code

```
decodeURIComponent("john%20doe");
//> john doe
```

Answer (score 1):

try this using javascript component

```
var url = decodeURIComponent($location.url());
```

Comment: you do know there is a difference between javascript and jQuery, do you?

Comment: neh, just wanted to point out that `decodeURIComponent` is not jQuery, but plain javascript... By posting the url to w3schools you didn't really make me feel you did understand the difference. By stating `jQuery is light version of javascript` I'm quite sure you don't really understand the difference ;) The blog post you're linking to is quite poor in explaining actually... not really a good source for information... Anyway, don't feel being attacked, no pun intended.